# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct myStruct *' from 'struct myStruct *'

Tags: objective-c, ios, incompatibletypeerror

I'm trying to learn objective c.

this is all in my .m file

```
@interface TetrisEngine ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) struct TetrisPiece *currPiece;
@end

struct TetrisPiece {
    int name;
    struct {
        int colOff, rowOff;
    } offsets[TetrisPieceRotations][TetrisPieceBlocks];
};
```

the contents of this next guy should not be relevant. i assume the return value is all you need to see in order to help out

```
static struct TetrisPiece pieces[TetrisNumPieces] = {...};

@implementation TetrisEngine
@synthesize currPiece;

- (void) nextPiece
    currPiece = &pieces[ ((random() % (TetrisNumPieces * 113)) + 3) % TetrisNumPieces];
```

and this is where i get the error: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct TetrisPiece *' from 'struct TetrisPiece *'

Comment: If you have OO facilities in a language, why use structs here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file var needs to be declared explicitly for the c-type pointer, like this...

```
@interface TetrisEngine () {
    // added curly braces and this
    struct TetrisPiece *currPiece;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) struct TetrisPiece *currPiece;
@end
```

The rest should work as is.  Though I agree with the other answer that there are more modern ways to declare structs in oo.

Comment: addition - If you use the @synthesize, on the implementation file, for your property there is no need to add it on declaration file (.h)(struct TetrisPiece *currPiece). If there is no instance variable that matches the name of a synthesized property, one is automatically created.

Comment: Thank you. Is this only the case for c-type pointers to structs? In other words, am I allowed to skip this explicit declaration for my remaining, objective-c type variables?

Comment: Yes, like @iluvatar_GR mentioned.  For object pointers, @ synthesize will do the declaration implicitly.

Comment: There isn't c-type pointers and object-c type pointers. They all are pointer and  they just have a memory address as a value. You need to declare all your instant variables (pointers or not) of your object (@interface) except if you use the @synthesize.

Comment: I must respectfully disagree.  Try this questioner's code for yourself...compiler error.  Replace the struct pointer with an object, and (as you point out correctly) the @synthesize will make the declaration implicitly.  You are right that c-type pointers and objects are very similar syntactically.  But they are not the same, one syntactic difference is illustrated here.  And syntax isn't reality... objects and bytes described by a struct are not at all the same.  Cheers.